# how do i use an an enter key stroke to submit a username and password

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onkeypress

I have a login button that works fine,it logs a user in etc.. but i want to allow the user to press the enter key to login as well. how do i do this.I tried a test using onkeypress but it didnt do anything as bellow

```
<form>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username id="username" />
       </div>
      <div class="form-group">
      <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="........" id="password" onkeypress=myFunction() /> //i just tried this myFunction() to see if it would give an alert but it doesnt
      </div>
     <div class="form-group">
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-login" id="btnLogin">Log in</button>

  </div>
  </div>
  </form>

function myFunction()
 { alert("button pressed")}
```

so how do i use the enter key to submit my request in javascript and jquery

Comment: You shouldn't have to do anything in JS

Comment: Why do you want to hook that up manually? If the focus is on a descendant of the `<form>` it should be submitted by the browser as per the default behavior.

Comment: you must use document, to hear from it the keypress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've placed the `input` within a `form` element which contains a submit button, you get this behaviour by default. To hook to it, use the `submit` event of the form, like this:

```js
$('form').on('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // only used to stop the form submission in this example
  console.log('form submitted');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" id=" username" />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group ">
    <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="........" id="password" />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-login" id="btnLogin">Log in</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Note that I fixed the missing `"` after the `placeholder` attribute in the first `input`. You also don't need the trailing space after all the attribute values, so I removed those too.

Comment: To clarify: there is no need for a submit button to even be present to let this happen.

Comment: @Balázs yes there is. There has to be a submit button.

Comment: Oh damn, really.

Comment: I'm afraid so. Here's the above without the button, you'll see nothing appears in the console: https://jsfiddle.net/e1mj5nhb/

Comment: Yes I've verified it myself, I was wrong. I would have bet a high amount on that it wasn't necessary.

Comment: @Balázs, this behaviour is explained here, https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#implicit-submission: _"If the form has no submit button, then the implicit submission mechanism must do nothing if the form has more than one field that blocks implicit submission"_, _"an element is a field that blocks implicit submission of a form element if it is an input element whose form owner is that form element and whose type attribute is in one of the following states: Text, Search, URL, Telephone, E-mail, Password, Date, Time, Number"_

Answer (score 0):

First you need to send the Event to the `myFunction()` function and add ID to your form to add submit manually::

**HTML**

```
<form id='myForm'>
<!-- form actions (etc..) -->
<input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="........" id="password" onkeypress=myFunction(e) />
<!-- form actions (etc..) -->
</form>
```

Now in ASCII the reenter code is `13` all you need to check is when the pressed key is reenter (13) then you need to take the event key code and call the submit function::

```
function myFunction(e)
var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
{
   if (code == "13")
    {
        //Calling the submit or clicking manually it 
        $( "#myForm" ).submit();   
    }
}
```